# All links to images are broken in a subdomain multi site environment

Tags: multisite, images

I've just installed a fresh copy of Wordpress 3.8.1, and then enabled the network feature using sub-domains.

In cPanel, I have the wildcard sub-domain pointing to the Wordpress folder, and Wordpress admin is working fine in the sub-domain.

When I am in a sub-domain's admin area, and I try to add an image to a page, the image displays as a broken placeholder.

However, I can see it has been uploaded to /wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/03/*.jpg

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^.*/files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Can you see what is wrong?

Here are some example images that will not display in the browser, even though they are in the file system:

- http://nsw.findrhinoplasty.com.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/03/find-best-rhinoplasty-surgeon-nsw.jpg

Here are some that *do* work:

- http://findrhinoplasty.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/logo-Aust.png

Comment: Are the images themselves broken or are the links to the images broken?

Comment: @s_ha_dum: The links to the images are broken.

Comment: What are the URLs? Maybe there is a clue.

Comment: @s_ha_dum: I've added a URL that does and doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use MU and I can't test this right now but...

If you started with a *fresh* 3.8.1, then your `.htaccess` file should look like this ([per the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration#.htaccess_and_Mod_Rewrite)):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Your `.htaccess` doesn't match, notably this line:

```
RewriteRule ^.*/files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]
```

That line is missing in the canonical file but included in yours. It is *similar to* a line from the WordPress 3.0 through 3.4.2 sub-folder example, but not an exact match:

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]
```

And also *similar to* the WordPress 3.0 through 3.4.2 subdomain example, but not an exact match to that either:

```
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]
```

Either way, you appear to have a not-quite-correct legacy rewrite rule in your `.htaccess` file.

That said, I don't think that rule should get in the way, though it makes me wonder how it got there.

I do notice that the `sites/` directory 404s (HttpFox output):

> GET   404 text/html   http://nsw.findrhinoplasty.com.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/

That makes me suspect a permissions problem on that directory or a parent.

Comment: I tried replacing .htaccess with the copy above, but the issue remains.